# i got following email from google play store after submitting wear app

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os

i got following email from google play store after submitting wear app..

App status: Your app has not been accepted into Android Wear. This does not affect your app’s status on Google Play.

Eligibility issues:
-Basic functionality of your app does not work as described. Be sure to test your app on a variety of different Android Wear devices and configurations.

-Your app does not have Android Wear functionality that’s visible to the user.

If you’re adding wearable features to notifications, make sure that they are triggering when appropriate.

If you’re building a wearable app, there may have been issues packaging it. Be sure to:
- Include all the permissions declared in the manifest file of the wearable app in the manifest file of the mobile app. For example, if you specify the VIBRATE permission for the wearable app, you must also add that permission to the mobile app.
- Ensure that both the wearable and mobile APKs have the same package name and version number.
- Sign your app.
- Test your app on a variety of different Android Wear devices and configurations.

please, can we get any demo or help of wear app in which mobile is sending bitmap or string to wear and the demo meets all the guidelines of official wear app quality which is mention in below link: 
https://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/wear.html

Comment: this is actually straight forward. `Eligibility issues: -Basic functionality of your app does not work as described. Be sure to test your app on a variety of different Android Wear devices and configurations.

-Your app does not have Android Wear functionality that’s visible to the user.`
You may want to review the functionalities for the `Android Wear`. It is technically not working according to the email.

Comment: actually i do not have android wear device but im testing in wear emulator and its working fine... can you provide me any link for demo.......

Comment: Because your android wear doesn't support for some wearable devices and may be unfortunately closed